# How can I solve this error occurring in Reactjs and Firebase Google Cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from Firebase Cloud Firestore and load it into my Reactjs app upon loading into the browser. However, I get the following error.

error message

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

The error occurs at the following line:

```
firebaseService.getUserData(authUser.uid).then(user => { ...
```

I get an initial page load followed by about a two second delay and then the error pops up. So I suspect it's coming from some missing promise or callback not being handled correctly. I have tried using `async` `await` in several places without success.

How can I solve this problem to fetch and load my data correctly?

Auth.js

```
import firebaseService from 'firebaseService';
...
class Auth extends Component {
  ...
  firebaseCheck = () => {
    firebaseService.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
      if (authUser) {
        this.props.showMessage({ message: 'Logging in with Firebase' });
        // Retrieve user data from Firebase
        firebaseService.getUserData(authUser.uid).then(user => { // <-- error occurs here
          this.props.setUserDataFirebase(user, authUser);
          this.props.showMessage({ message: 'Logged in with Firebase' });
        })
      }
    });
  };
}
```

firebaseService.js

```
getUserData = userId => {
  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    return;
  }
  const docRef = this.firestore.doc('users/myuserid');
  docRef.get().then(doc => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
      return doc.data;
    } else {
      console.log("No such document!");
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the `getUserData` function, you need to return a Promise before the function ends. When you call `docRef.get`, I'm assuming that is an asynchronous call, so while that is happening, the function ends and returns `undefined`. By the time it gets to `return doc.data`, it's too late.

```
getUserData = userId =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      reject();
    }
    docRef.get().then(doc => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        resolve(doc.data);
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
        reject();
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      reject();
    });
  });
```

Comment: @Mowzer Your edit is incorrect. You cannot use `return` there because the code is not enclosed in curly braces. It should have worked the way it was. Didn't it?

Comment: Hey good catch. My actual code did enclose it all in curly braces. But I removed them and everything works as you originally wrote it. Thanks again and good final catch! 